# Optimization ideas : apply a LUT (lookup table) on an image

Tags: image, optimization, lookup-tables

I currently work on some project using LUTs to modify colors of images.

My problem is that my program is not optimized...

What my program does:
* Opens a LUT file (.cube) and stores the values in the memory
* On each pixel of the image, trilinear interpolation is used to change the colors using the LUT

What I've tried:
* Downscaling the image, but the process still takes so much time...

How do programs such as Premiere pro or Davinci Resolve can apply a LUT to a footage and read it at 24fps? My program takes 10s to apply a LUT on a jpg/DNG file !

Comment: What resolution? And do you have any code? I just give it a quick try and easily reached 40+ FPS at 1080p, without doing anything especially interesting.

Comment: even with a small resolution... here is my code: http://iswift.org/playground?btt6j1  (you cannot run it, but it's jsut for the formatting);

Comment: Ok, looks a bit complicated. I reached the above speed by pre-processing the LUT to have all 2^24 entries so the image processing step is just a lookup per pixel.

Comment: Okay, so that means that it is possible to reach high-fps rates by using the method of -applying the LUT on each pixel- ?

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way to do this would be in the GPU, which can do many simple interpolation and lookup instructions simultaneously on many pixels.

This article: https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/GPUGems2/gpugems2_chapter24.html
describes the algorithm for you, and it's simple enough it's trivial to port it over to OpenGL or another GPU scripting language:

```
void main(in float2 sUV : TEXCOORD0,
out half4 cOut : COLOR0,
    const uniform samplerRECT imagePlane,
    const uniform sampler3D lut,
    const uniform float3 lutSize)
{
    // get raw RGB pixel values
    half3 rawColor = texRECT(imagePlane, sUV).rgb;

    // calculate scale and offset values
    half3 scale = (lutSize - 1.0) / lutSize;
    half3 offset = 1.0 / (2.0 * lutSize);

    // apply the LUT
    cOut.rgb = tex3D(lut, scale * rawColor + offset);
}
```

Outside of that you will have to load the LUT as a uniform array into the GPU with your application code, and then stream every video frame into the GPU so it can pass it through your fragment shader in a render/work loop. This is most likely what professional video editing programs do, in order to apply LUTs with realtime video constraints.

**P.S.** harold's comment about precalculating the lookup entries is also a valid way to speed your process up, making the operation purely a memory access with the lookup. It'll still probably be orders of magnitude less efficient than GPU processing because of how much slower CPU memory access is compared to what the GPU does, and it's very memory inefficient, depending on the system you do it on and the dimensionality and size of your LUT.

For example, let's say you want to make the 'full' 3D LUT for 24-bit RGB. That means your final cube needs to have an edge of size 255, meaning your final size is this: 255^3 * 3 (RGB) * 2 (float) bytes, for a total of nearly 100MB. Obviously if it is just a 1D LUT this might not be an issue, or with lower color bit-depth, however this method is still inefficient compared to letting the GPU handle the interpolation for you.